# How to make users gain root privileges from another account?

Tags: 12.10, root

How can I make something like that:

There are two users: user with normal privileges, and administrator with admin privileges.

I want to make it like that:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo vim 
[sudo] password for administrator: <admin's password here>
```

And I am on the administrator account now.

Comment: Use sudoedit: `man sudoedit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant that when logged in as `user` you want to execute a command as `administrator` then you need to do:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo -u administrator vim
```

However, the `user`'s password will be asked not the one from `adminitrator`. To do so you need to run as administrator (hmm) the following command to configure `sudo`:

```
visudo
```

Then scroll down in the opened file and look for other `Defaults` definition. In this section, preferrably at the end of it, add a new line with:

```
Defaults targetpw
```

And save the file and exit. Note that this will change the default behaviour for all sudo users, so if your user `administrator` needs to use `sudo` to have root privilege, you would better know the `root` password!

Answer (score 6):

Simply add the user to the sudo group:

`sudo adduser <username> sudo`

More detailed explanation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Allowing_other_users_to_run_sudo

If you really need to run vim as a user named "administrator" (not root!) you should use

`sudo -u adminstrator vim`

But even in that case the normal user has to be member of the sudo group.

Comment: This will give `root` permissions to the user not the `administrator` account permissions. I agree that in most of the cases, this will be the same as `administrator` account probably is a sudoer, but not always! :)

Comment: @laurent: Agreed. I'm assuming "administrator with admin privileges" means smth with root permissions.

Comment: sure this is a valid assumption in my opinion. I just wanted to point out to the OP that his particular situation could be a little different if (for example) he mounts NFS directories with root_squash but usually it won't be the case.

Comment: Enhanced answer to adopt laurent's comments.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo vim` would mean to execute the `vim` command as super-user. If you are looking for the command to start a shell, use

```
sudo -i
```

or

```
sudo su
```

These will have you type the password of your **user**, and the user needs to be in the sudoers file.

If you don't want the user to be added to that file, you could just use the command

```
su
```

which will have you type in the **root** (administrator) account.

And finally, if there is an account called `administrator`, you could do

```
su administrator
```

to gain access to that.

Comment: +1 for the last part: `su administrator` is exactly what the OP is asking for (from what I understood).

Comment: Please note that `sudo su` is essentially equivalent to `sudo -s` (not to `sudo -i`, which is essentially equivalent to `sudo su -`).